# Select row with regex instead of unique value

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

Hello everyone I'm making a really simple lookup in a pandas dataframe, what I need to do is to lookup for the input I'm typing as a regex instead of == myvar

So far this is what I got which is very inneficient because there's a lot of Names in my DataFrame that instead of matching a list of them which could be

```
Name         LastName
NAME 1       Some Awesome
Name 2       Last Names
Nam e 3      I can keep going
Bane         Writing this is awesome
BANE 114     Lets continue
```

However this is what I got

```
import pandas as pd
contacts = pd.read_csv("contacts.csv")
print("regex contacts")
nameLookUp = input("Type the name you are looking for: ")
print(nameLookUp)
desiredRegexVar = contacts.loc[contacts['Name'] == nameLookUp]
print(desiredRegexVar)
```

I have to type 'NAME 1' or 'Nam e 3' in order results or I wont get any at all, I tried using this but it didnt work

```
#regexVar = "^" + contacts.filter(regex = nameLookUp)
```

Thanks for the answer @Code Different

The code looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import re
namelookup = input("Type the name you are looking for: ")
pattern = '^' + re.escape(namelookup)
match = contactos['Cliente'].str.contains(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE, na=False)
print(contactos[match])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). Tweak the pattern as appropriate:

```
import re

pattern = '^' + re.escape(namelookup)
match = contacts['Name'].str.contains(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
contacts[match]
```

Comment: Thanks this is the right answer code looks like this in my case, btw can you explain what is that 'import re' for? have a good one!

Comment: `re` is Python's regular expression module. Within this answer, I needed the `re.escape` function (in case the user enter some weird names like `^John` -- we need to clean that up) and `re.IGNORECASE` (which is just an int but nicer than typing a magic number)